# Converting datetime code in SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the following code - I am trying to convert from SQL Server to Oracle. The code works perfectly in SQL Server, but not in Oracle. How can I convert the ff?

This is the code from SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RLL.dbo.AlphaToDate4(D.NEW_DATA), 103) 
CaptureDate
FROM
    Employees
```

This is the formats of `NEW_DATA` is sometimes characters or numbers eg (01105118,0,.5,EP,ANSTAT)

I am trying to write the following code in oracle but gives me an error

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE((D.NEW_DATA),'DD/MM/YYYY')  CAPTUREDATE
```

Comment: Well, what does `RLL.dbo.AlphaToDate4` do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SELECT TO_DATE('2012-06-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Table

Comment: Conversion style 103 in SQL Server is `dd/mm/yyyy` so the `TO_DATE` specification needs to match that.